# Ad cell after every five cells in tableview

Tags: ios, tableview

I need add an ad cell with only image after every five news cells in table view.

If I will add second section for ad cells, an ad cell will be shown after all news cells.
If I will add an ad cell when `indexPath.row == 4`, my fifth news cell won't appear because of `cell.details = news[indexPath.row]`.

Any suggestions how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: did you got the solution?

Comment: I am currently implementing same thing and not able to find any solution, so if you have solved then kindly share it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the method cellForRowAtIndexPath of UITableViewDataSource do next:

```
if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
// configure ad cell
} else {
// configure usual cell with news[indexPath.row - (indexPath.row / 5)]
}
```

Comment: then i lose my fifth news

Comment: The problem with this is that my custom cell covers items that are in my data source. What would be the best way to configure this so that all of my data source shows along with the custom cells added every nth row?

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out a system to get the right data for your cells:

> 0 NEWS
>
> 1 NEWS
>
> 2 NEWS
>
> 3 NEWS
>
> 4 NEWS
>
> 5 AD     <----- "5." => (currentRow % 5 == 0)
>
> 6 NEWS    <----- "6." => (6 - (currentRow / 5)

You see a system?

You can do something like:

```
if ((row % 5) == 0) {
    //Ad stuff here
} else {
    data = tabledata[row - (row/5)];
    //news stuff here using data
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this but my custom cell is covering what's in my data in some places.

Answer (score 1):

do like this ..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 4;//add your own number, might be totalNumberOfNewsItems/5
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
   int reqIndex = indexPath.section*(5) + indexPath.row;
   // get data from array like news[reqIndex];
 }
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // return your ad view based on section value
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44; // change to your required value
}
```

Comment: it's interesting, try it later

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
       //configure ad cell
    } else {
       //configure usual cell
    }
}
```