# Adding an ad after every 5 cells in tableview is replacing content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've search on stackoverflow for a hint on how to do that and [I found this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282607/ad-cell-after-every-five-cells-in-tableview) but that did not solved my problem, I want the same thing( add an advertise **after** every 5 rows), and I tried the solution mentioned there, but what I'm getting is the first row is being replaced by the ad, as the 5th, and so on, my normal content is being replaced by the ad.
So I want to achieve this:

```
row 0 = normal content
row 1 = normal content
row 2 = normal content
row 3 = normal content
row 4 = normal content
row 5 = ad
row 6 = normal content
...
```

here is what I tried:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0) {
            if let cellBanner = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellBanner", for: indexPath) as? BannerCell {

                return cellBanner
            } else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
        } else {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? AnuncioCell {
                if AnunciosService.instance.anuncios.count >= indexPath.row {
                    let anuncio = AnunciosService.instance.anuncios[indexPath.row]
                    let rowsToLoadFromBottom = 5;
                    let rowsLoaded = AnunciosService.instance.anuncios.count

                    if (!self.fetchingMore && (indexPath.row - (indexPath.row / 5) >= (rowsLoaded - rowsToLoadFromBottom))) {
                        let totalRows = AnunciosService.instance.anunciosCount
                        let remainingAnunciosToLoad = totalRows - rowsLoaded;
                        if (remainingAnunciosToLoad > 0) {
                            self.loadMoreAnuncios()
                        }
                    }

                    cell.configureCell(anuncio: anuncio)
                    let checkValue = Double(anuncio.user.nota)!
                    if checkValue < 1.0 {
                        cell.notaView.isHidden = true
                    }else{
                        cell.notaView.isHidden = false
                    }
                    if anuncio.destaque {
                        cell.destaque.isHidden = false
                    } else {
                        cell.destaque.isHidden = true
                    }
                    if anuncio.status == 0 {
                        if cell.imgAnuncio.image != nil{
                            Noir(originalImage: cell.imgAnuncio)
                        }
                        cell.sold_out.isHidden = false
                        cell.selectionStyle = .none
                        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
                    } else {
                        cell.sold_out.isHidden = true
                        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
                        cell.selectionStyle = .default
                    }

                }

                return cell
            } else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
        }

    }
```

numberOfRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if AnunciosService.instance.anuncios.count == 0 {
            return 0
        }
        return AnunciosService.instance.anuncios.count + BannersService.instance.banners.count
    }
```

Comment: So you want an ad along with your normal data?

Comment: @Xcoder yes, that's it

Comment: what is your tableView `numberOfRowsInSection` value? are you including your ads in there?

Comment: @MRFrhn I've edited the question with that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, for those who want to know how I solved it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let index = indexPath.row + 1
        if (index % 6 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0 && index/6 <= BannersService.instance.banners.count) {
            let cellBanner = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellBanner", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell

            return cellBanner
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AnuncioCell
            let index = indexPath.row - (indexPath.row / 6)
            if AnunciosService.instance.anuncios.count > index {
                let anuncio = AnunciosService.instance.anuncios[index]
                let rowsToLoadFromBottom = 5;
                let rowsLoaded = AnunciosService.instance.anuncios.count

                if (!self.fetchingMore && (index >= (rowsLoaded - rowsToLoadFromBottom))) {
                    let totalRows = AnunciosService.instance.anunciosCount
                    let remainingAnunciosToLoad = totalRows - rowsLoaded;
                    if (remainingAnunciosToLoad > 0) {
                        self.loadMoreAnuncios()
                    }
                }

                cell.configureCell(anuncio: anuncio)
                let checkValue = Double(anuncio.user.nota)!
                if checkValue < 1.0 {
                    cell.notaView.isHidden = true
                }else{
                    cell.notaView.isHidden = false
                }
                if anuncio.destaque {
                    cell.destaque.isHidden = false
                } else {
                    cell.destaque.isHidden = true
                }
                if anuncio.status == 0 {
                    if cell.imgAnuncio.image != nil {
                        Noir(originalImage: cell.imgAnuncio)
                    }
                    cell.sold_out.isHidden = false
                    cell.selectionStyle = .none
                    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
                } else {
                    cell.sold_out.isHidden = true
                    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
                    cell.selectionStyle = .default
                }
            }

            return cell
        }

    }
```